# How to convert the JSON in Objective-C below to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, json, swift, encoding

I had try to convert the following code to

Objective-C

```
NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Swift

```
let json = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json?.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)), options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions)
```

but i keep getting this error

> Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with:
>   Data?, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.Type)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take advantage of `Swift` with optional values too. Try this.

```
if let data = json?.data(using: .utf8),
    let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) {
    //jsonObject
}
```